# Порядок работы операторов в XmlHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, запрос, get

Прочитал [С чего начать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/%D0%A1_%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C). Там код идет в следующей последовательности

```js
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };
httpRequest.open('GET', url, true);
httpRequest.send(null);
```

Но почему проверка состояния запроса httpRequest (получен ли ответ с сервера) и назначение обработчика  - `httpRequest.onreadystatechange` происходит до открытия запроса и отправки на сервер? Логично оператор
`httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };` поставить после

```js
httpRequest.open('GET', url, true);
httpRequest.send(null);
```

Comment: Порядок операторов это другое - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `onreadystatechange` не происходит ничего «здесь и сейчас», вы просто присваиваете ваш обработчик в данный этап запроса, то есть он вызовется в момент триггера это хука, по сути на данном этапе вы делаете настройку для запроса, но это конфигурирование нужно сделать непосредственно до выполнения. А `open` и `send` вы непосредственно вызываете, как метод, то есть инициируется выполнение какого-либо этапа, тут порядок вызова уже важен.